# Error generates with usingOAuth2

Tags: android

I am using Google drive API with my eclipse android project which is to upload images in to google drive programmatically. I followed the link https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android to develop a sample application, but getting error with usingOAuth2 in oncreate method.

i am getting error like The method usingOAuth2(Context, Collection) in the type GoogleAccountCredential is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity, String) in the given line

```
     credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
```

I know this fault is in second argument but i followed as per the document given by the google drive so i need to change the arguments if i change usingOAuth2 to usingAudience it executes but not able to see the images which i uploaded into drive
Could anyone please help me to sort out this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

usingOAuth2 is deprecated instead of that we have to use usingOAuth2(this, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));